# Aplicam-se as formas normais no spring boot?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Eu tenho 2 classes, a classe Pessoa e a classe Endereço. A classe Pessoa é dona da classe Endereço, pois uma pessoa pode ficar sem endereços mas um endereço **não** pode ficar sem pessoa; então a relação é **um para um** (ignore o fato que um usuário pode ter muitos endereços). As classes são assim:

```java
@Entity @Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    //... 

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;

    // ... getters e setters
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    //...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private User user;

    //... getters and setters
}
```

Parece que não há nada demais nessas classes, mas o principal problema é a forma normal aplicada nessa relação. No gerenciamento do banco de dados existem formas normais (padrões usados para criar tabelas e relações) e as principais são 3: a primeira forma normal, a segunda forma normal e a terceira forma normal. Eu estou acostumado a usar a primeira forma normal, onde a tabela filha tem a id da tabela pai, no caso, a tabela Endereço depende da tabela Pessoa, então a tabela Endereço deveria ter uma coluna especialmente para a id da tabela Pessoa. Mas, prestando atenção nas Annotations, a classe Usuário tem uma `@JoinColumn`, o que isso significa que na criação das tabelas do banco a tabela Usuário tem a id do Endereço e a endereço apenas tem uma anotação simples que indica que está sendo mapeada pela Usuário, o que isso é contra a primeira forma normal. A maioria dos pequenos tultoriais na internet como [essa](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one) mostra a classe Pai tendo a id da classe filha. A questão é se pode colocar o `joi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No relacionamento bidirecional one-to-one, segundo a própria documentação do JPA (https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0#a516):

1. A entidade A faz referencia a entidade B.
2. A entidade B faz referencia a entidade A.
3. A entidade A é proprietária do relacionamento.

Então a tabela A contém uma chave estrangeira para a tabela B.

Ex:

```
class Empregado{
      @OneToOne
      private Gabinete gabinete;
      // etc
}


class Gabinete{
      @OneToOne(mappedBy="gabinete")
      private Empregado empregadoAtual;
      // etc
}
```

Neste exemplo, Empregado é o lado proprietário, e portanto, a entidade Gabinete na entidade Empregado é mapeada pelo campo gabinete, por isso a referência `mappedBy="gabinete"` diz que "gabinete" não é o proprietário.

Caso você queria evitar o relacionamento bidirecional, você pode usar o relacionamento unidirecional one-to-one. Neste caso, o seu código ficaria assim:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    // etc
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    // etc
}
```